# writing image data to text file to creat BMP file

Tags: windows, image, text, rgb, bmp

I have 1x1 pixel image in BMP. I opened it in notepad. Select ALL and paste the whole data over Serial port monitor, to see what exactly character are in the file..whatever...
  I simply copy the data of BMP file opened in notepad and paste it in another text file, save it as .BMP extension. But no IMAGE is formed. as invalid BMP file.
   when I check the properties of both images (original image and   the image i created by copying the data to new file) by right clicking on it, there is difference in advance information. whats the problem? how can I do that. 
  I have image data in my Controller and want to save it on SD-card as bmp image....

Answer (score 0):

`cp ./image.bmp ./image-copy.bmp`

This will allow you to copy a bitmap to another file which contains a valid copy of the original bitmap on Unix-like operating systems. In Windows, use `copy file.bmp file-copy.bmp`.

What you're looking for is a hex editor, if you want to view the actual binary data of the file. Notepad represents certain unprintable characters as completely different printable characters. When you open any binary data file into Notepad and copy its contents to the clipboard, you are not actually copying the binary data. You are copying Notepad's attempt to translate unprintable data into viewable data.